# Find any part of a string of text from a range of cells

Tags: text, indexing, find, match, vlookup

I have two lists of street addresses that have a combination of street numbers and names in one cell.  One list is a key, if you will, of how the addresses are labeled in our company, and the other list is all of the addresses that customers used to get a package to us.  For example![Address Key][1]

is the correct address format.  The other list has errors within the address because there may be errors with order, fat fingered street numbers, or spelling errors of the street names. I'd like to create a formula or find a way that looks for any portion of the second list, and have it return a "yes" or "no" if it is an address in the address key.  The second list that I need to lookup with is below.![enter image description here][2]

You can see that the addresses that the customers enter do not match how we label our addresses.  Hopefully there is a way for me to look up any part of the address that they entered against our key, and have it return a value that is associated with each address in the key.  For example, the first address is location 100.  Even though the customer list doesn't have that address entered correctly, i'm hopping it can find a part of the address they entered in our list.

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Vlookup with a 'TRUE' parameter in the RangeLookup argument.  That way the Vlookup will return an approximate match against your company list.  You may need to reformat the data a bit (e.g. concatenate house number and street name together) and do some iterations to get the final result that you need.  You haven't added any screen shots so I can't see the exact format of your data.

Comment: how do I enter a screen shot if I don't have a high enough reputation on this site? My data is already concatenated.. so I'd think if anything I would want to separate it since there are different parts of each txt that are incorrect (ie. street number is wrong, street name is wrong, street extension is wrong)